# How to fade in fade/fade out with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use this script to show my #header on 'page1', 'page2', 'page3' ONLY but fade it out on , 'page4' then fade it back in again on 'page5'

This is currently working fine with my #footer which is hidden on all pages except 'page5' which it fades into.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fn.fullpage({
            anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4','page5'],
            slidesColor: ['#000', '#000', '#000', '#000', '#000'],
            'scrollOverflow': true,
            css3: true,
            fixedElements: '#header, #footer',
            afterRender: function () {
                $('#footer').hide();
                $('#header').show();
            },
            afterLoad: function (anchor, index) {
                if (index == 1, 2, 3, 4) {}
                $('#footer').fadeOut();
                if (index == 5) {
                    $('#footer').fadeIn();
                    }
                    if (index == 4) {}
                $('#header').fadeOut();
                if (index == 1, 2, 3, 5) {
                    $('#header').show();
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q79kF/

Thanks for the help...

Comment: You aren't including your HTML, the jQuery library, or plugin in your jsFiddle...

Comment: And the syntax is incorrect in the fiddle, you should fix it up so it can run.

Comment: If you are showing only scripting in jsfiddle , they there is no need of that , we can see it right here

Comment: `if (index == 1, 2, 3, 4)`  really?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok.. It might have been a problem in sequence you have written.. With the code which you have provided, I believe this could be your problem.

header visible in 1,2,3 .. fades out at 4 .. fades in at 5
footer not visible in 1,2,3,4 .. but fades in at 5

Try

```
            //if (index == 1, 2, 3, 4) {} //You dont need this anyway
            if(index == 1, 2, 3){
                $('#header').show(); //try using .css('display','block') if show() didnt work
                $('#footer').hide(); //try using .css('display','none') if hide() didnt work
            }
            if(index == 4){
                $('#header').fadeOut();
            }
            if(index == 5){
                $('#header').fadeIn();
                $('#footer').fadeIn();
            }
```

Try tweaking a bit.. This is what I have understood.. In case I m wrong let me know, will try to help you..

Comment: What is `if(index == 1, 2, 3)`?

Comment: Thank you so much Mohammed - worked perfectly! ;-)